# HTML5 appcache for media only

Tags: html, offline-caching, html5-appcache

I want to cache javascript libraries and other static assets - but no HTML whatsoever.

I was under the impression

```
CACHE MANIFEST

somefiles.js
somemorefiles.js

NETWORK:
*
```

Would do the job. It caches the html anyway. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML page containing the reference to the cache manifest is always added to the cache. See the [specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#introduction-5).

> Note: Authors are encouraged to include the main page in the manifest also,
>   but in practice the page that referenced the manifest is automatically
>   cached even if it isn't explicitly mentioned.

Comment: Okay. Is it possible to explicitly tell it to never do that?

Comment: On a highly dynamic site, after all, that's really problematic.

Comment: No. The goal is offline web applications, not optimizing resources for part of the application. That is something that should be done by getting the browser to cache those resources using conventional means. And it's up to the browser and user if that works or not.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot for your help - you don't also happen to know how to shut it off in a way that removes it rather than just causes it to update or fallback?

Comment: Remove the reference to the cache manifest? Sure, first change the manifest url to something invalid so it causes an error when you load the page, after that you can can remove it altogether. Kind of hacky but that is the way to remove a manifest.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a hidden iframe with a reference to page with a manifest. Then remove the manifest from your HTML page that you don't want to be cached.

Comment: This would cause the manifest to reload. It would not cause the browser to delete it. Right?